# Why array pass by reference, but struct pass by value implicitly in C?

Tags: objective-c, c, linux

Why they design like this?  I am very confused.

Update : I really want to know the answer of the question. I Googled but I can find nothing quite useful.

I think there maybe two reasons:

**One** : technical. Maybe it is hard to implement by the compiler (struct pass by reference). If the answer is this one. Please explain it.

**Two**: good for usage(programming). As i think, it is more elegant (or beautiful?), if struct pass by reference. I can not find some examples that show the advantage (strut pass by value).  My programming career is not very long. In practice, I prefer to pass struct to a function as a pointer(pointer occupy less space on stack).

Comment: +1 - this is a very good question about C with a correct, technical answer.  I think the downvote did not realize this.

Comment: @djechlin: The question asks why it was designed this way.  That calls for a history answer, not a technical answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt - there is a technical reason.  The historical reason is "because there was a technical reason."  Hypothetically if the OP were asking about the historical explanation, which I doubt because people don't get "very confused" by historical factoids they don't know, it would indicate the OP does not understand the technical reason, and therefore would behoove us to help the OP with that issue first - since bluntly you can't write maintainable code in C without understanding this.

Comment: @djechlin i agree with you, thanks. :-)

Comment: The question should rather by "Why are arrays not passed by value" - now THAT is unusual. If you want to pass a pointer to struct, you always can do so explicitly - why forcing it for you? With arrays passing by value cannot be done (unless you wrap a struct around them).

Comment: I disagree with this question's status of "closed as not constructive". Not knowing the semantics of structs might lead someone to use one when it is not appropriate, so "why is it designed this way?" really is a fair technical question.

Answer (score -1):

you may imagine array as a set containing consecutive memory location with the name of the array as the pointer to the first memory address of that set.

So it should be obvious now that when you pass an array by it's name, you are actually passing a copy of the address of that memory.

A structure, however is a set of objects, so when you pass a structure name, you are passing a copy of the objects in that set.

PS: this is a very basic C concept and an obvious doubt, better read a good C book to clear your concept further.

Comment: And if you pass a struct that has an array inside...  no, an array is not merely a pointer to the beginning of the content, although it easily decays to a pointer.

Comment: seems "copy of objects" is misleading. in case of arrar, i mean the copy of the array.

Comment: -1 on the technical point that arrays are passed by reference not by memory.  This is "more or less" the same but the array/pointer distinction does matter.

Comment: "you are actually passing a copy of the address of that memory"
this is all i said about array passing. What is wrong in this statement. Enlighten me.

Comment: `int x[10]; int* y = x;` fails to compile.  Disagreeing that "you may imagine ... name of the array as the pointer to the first memory address."

Comment: @djechlin it compiles perfectly. http://ideone.com/IcJDM

Comment: @djechlin Thanks, please see the question again

Comment: @LouXiu It is not hard for compiler to pass struct by reference. It is in turn faster and popular in practice.
the compiler here is doing everything logical. when you are passing a structure "a" as in f(a), you are "passing by value" the object "a" as you would expect with any other type like int,char.
when you are passing an array (say a[10]) as in f(a), here also you are "passing by value" "a" which holds the memory address of the beginning of the array. So, the same chunk memory area is also being used in the function.

Comment: as djechlin said, array and pointers are a bit different, but their difference here doesn't play any hindrance in the answer to your question.

Answer (score -2):

the array pass, actually is to pass address by value. In c, there has no pass by reference.

I think the reason to no pass whole value of array is that

first, the performance.

Second, since we can use the pointer as an array, the compiler can't know the size of memory that pointer points to, so can't to pass all value in array to function. 
C definitely can be designed to know exact size of array, and pass value of array.But then, we can't use the pointer in array way, we can't use any malloc array.

Comment: well, compiler knows the size of memory of statically allocated arrays, but you got a point there for dynamically allocated arrays

Comment: The unique exception to "no pass by value" is references.  An array is a reference to memory which behaves more like a pointer.

Comment: Furthermore this is incorrect.  `foo(char[16] c)`; is a valid function sig (or maybe `char c[16]` I always forget) and this function knows how much memory needs to be passed to it.

Comment: @djechlin  foo(char c[16]), the compiler can be designed to know size of c. but current C compiler doesn't know, the sizeof(c) is sizeof(char*). To specify the array size in parameter isn't good way to C.

Comment: `char c[10]; printf("%d\n", sizeof(c))` prints 10.

Comment: @djechlin look this http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html

Comment: @djechlin try it with malloc()

Comment: @nims yes malloc deals with pointers not arrays.  Rolandxu thanks for the link, I'll brush up on K&R since I don't have this topic fully down.  sometimes passing by array is unavoidable though e.g. 2d arrays.